# Image pulling issue on Kubernetes from private repository

Tags: bash, kubernetes, docker-registry

I created registry credits and when I apply on pod like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-reg
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: registry.io.io/simple-node
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
```

it works succesfly pull image

But if I try to do this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: node123
  namespace: node123
spec:
  replicas: 5
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 2
      maxUnavailable: 0
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: node123
  template:
      metadata:
          labels:
              name: node123
      spec:
          containers:
              - name: node123
                image: registry.io.io/simple-node
                ports:
                - containerPort: 3000
          imagePullSecrets:
             - name: regcred
```

On pod will get error: ImagePullBackOff

when I describe it getting

> Failed to pull image "registry.io.io/simple-node": rpc error: code =
> Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get
> https://registry.io.io/v2/simple-node/manifests/latest: no basic auth
> credentials

Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: First of all, are you sure `registry.io.io/simple-node` is the correct image?  `registry.io.io` seem like it might be a typo

Comment: Checked that the pull secret is available in the namespace used for the Deployment?

Comment: @Kris.J it can be an issue should I always create pull secret when creating new namespace?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We are always running images from private registry. And this checklist might help you :

1. Put your params in env variable in your terminal to have single source of truth:

   ```
   export DOCKER_HOST=registry.io.io
   export DOCKER_USER=<your-user>
   export DOCKER_PASS=<your-pass>
   ```
2. Make sure that you can authenticate & the image really exist

   ```
   echo $DOCKER_PASS | docker login -u$DOCKER_USER --password-stdin $DOCKER_HOST
   docker pull ${DOCKER_HOST}/simple-node
   ```
3. Make sure that you created the Dockerconfig secret in the same namespace of pod/deployment;

   ```
   namespace=mynamespace # default
   kubectl -n ${namespace} create secret docker-registry regcred \
     --docker-server=${DOCKER_HOST} \
     --docker-username=${DOCKER_USER} \
     --docker-password=${DOCKER_PASS} \
     --docker-email=anything@will.work.com
   ```
4. Patch the service account used by the Pod with the secret

   ```
   namespace=mynamespace
   kubectl -n ${namespace} patch serviceaccount default \
     -p '{"imagePullSecrets": [{"name": "regcred"}]}'
   # if the pod use another service account, 
   #     replace "default" by the relevant service account
   ```

   or

   Add `imagePullSecrets` in the pod :

   ```
   imagePullSecrets:
    - name: regcred
   containers:
    - ....
   ```

Comment: It was issue with namespace.. Thanks